# how to get a value of Realm query?

Tags: android, realm-mobile-platform

I use Android Studio 3.0.1
I get query result and want to get inside a query, i.e. to get a string "token" to be able to greet a user by name.

```
RealmResults query = mRealmInstance.where(Config.class).equalTo("name","John").findAllAsync();
            if(query.size() > 0){

                //how to get a value of a name?

            } else if (query.size() == 0){
                Log.e("query","query size is "+query.size());
            }
```

Comment: Did you checked this link? https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Comment: Yes, I did. I just cannot solve my problem based on this materials.

Comment: I would guess you should type string name = query.name or something like this. I would probably rename "query" to something else to make it less confusing.

Comment: can not resolve symbol 'name' referring to the second position:            
       String name = User.name;